# How to copy a resource to a file in another location in Java

Tags: java, file, resources, guava

I'm trying to copy a resource in my project onto another location on the disk. So far, I have this code:

```
if (!file.exists()){
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        Files.copy(new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
            public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
                return Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + name);
            }
        }, file);                   
    } catch (IOException e) {
        file = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

And it works fine, but the `InputSupplier` class is deprecated, so I was wondering if there was a better way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation for the Guava [`InputSupplier` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html):

> For `InputSupplier<? extends InputStream>`, use [`ByteSource`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteSource.html) instead. For `InputSupplier<? extends Reader>`, use [`CharSource`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CharSource.html). Implementations of `InputSupplier` that don't fall into one of those categories do not benefit from any of the methods in `common.io` and should use a different interface. This interface is scheduled for removal in December 2015.

So in your case, you're looking for `ByteSource`:

```
Resources.asByteSource(url).copyTo(Files.asByteSink(file));
```

See [this section](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/IOExplained) of the Guava Wiki for more information.

---

If you're looking for a pure Java (no external libraries) version, you can do the following:

```
try (InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/" + name)) {
    Files.copy(is, Paths.get("C:\\some\\file.txt"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred copying the resource
}
```

Note that this is only valid for Java 7 and higher.

Comment: I just found the pure java solution and was about to post it then I saw your edit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Note that the pure Java version you show has an important difference to the Guava version: it doesn't even try to close the stream for the resource. The Guava version guarantees that the stream is closed after the copy, regardless of whether it succeeds or fails.

Comment: @ColinD He used "try with resources" block, so the InputStream will be closed automatically.

Comment: @Pavitra: My comment referred to the answer that NonameSL had posted, which was deleted, not the answer this comment is on.